# Is my EV3 controller bricked?

Tags: ev3

My EV3 controller seems to be 'stuck' in this state:

[image]

Is the device operating properly?
If not, is there a procedure that can unbrick the controller?

Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry to see that no one has answered such simple question you have. I recommend that you look it up before you post a question about it. There are videos on how to fix this, too.